# How to redirect/ render to another controller's view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Once the pet is saved, I want to redirect to treats/show controller. I tried doing this but it takes me back to pets/show.

```
def create
    @pets = Pet.new(pet_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pet.save
        format.html { redirect_to @treat}
        format.json { template: treats/show, status: :created, location: @pet }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @pet.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this for your redirect path:

```
format.html  { redirect_to(treat_path(@treat) }
```

Comment: edit: sorry I was wrong. It takes me to the index. `redirect_to(treats_path(@treat)`

Comment: Are you using `treats_path` or `treat_path`?

Comment: treat_path gives me error saying No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"treat", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]. Sorry about treats_path... the errors are driving me a bit nuts today.

Comment: In your `routes.rb` do you have `resources :treats`?

Comment: but your answer is correct I got my associations wrong and it was throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Your `@pets` variable should be `@pet`...**

Like this:

```
def create
   @pet = Pet.new pet_params
```

--

**2. You aren't defining your `@treat` variable:**

```
@treat = Treat.find params[:treat_id] ?
```

This is shown up here:

```
{:action=>"show", :controller=>"treat", :id=>nil}
```

So the answer is that you need to define `@treat`. Because I don't know your *associations*, or how you want `@treat` to be populated, there are two ways to create it:

Either pull it from the `association` (IE `@pet.treat`) or invoke it explicitly: (`@treat -`)...

For simplicity, you're best doing the following:

```
def create
    @pets = Pet.new pet_params 
    @treat = Treat.find [[[num - where do you get this from?]]]

    ...
end
```

--

If you had your models set up as such:

```
#app/models/pet.rb
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :treats
end

#app/models/treat.rb
class Treat < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :pet
end
```

You could use the following:

```
def create
    @pet = Pet.new pet_params
    @treat = @pet.treat.new treat_params

    respond_to do ...

end

private

def treat_params
   params.require(:treat).permit(:treat, :params)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Rich. Very well explained as usual. :-)